# Expected value of a particular sum of binomial random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ a discrete random variable which distribution is defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X=j)=\sum_{k=0}^j \mathbb{P}(Y=k) \mathbb{P}(Z=j-k)
\end{equation}
where $Y,Z$ are independent random variable distributed as $Y \sim Bin(n,p)$, $Z \sim Bin(m,q)$, $j\in \{0, \dots , N \}$ is finite and $n,m<N$.

I would like to find the mean of X,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{j=0}^N j \mathbb{P}(X=j)=\sum_{j=0}^N j\sum_{k=0}^j \mathbb{P}(Y=k) \mathbb{P}(Z=j-k)
\end{equation}
I tried to expand this sum and I found
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^N j\sum_{k=0}^j \mathbb{P}(Y=k) \mathbb{P}(Z=j-k)=\sum_{j=0}^N \left(\mathbb{P}(Y=j)\sum_{k=0}^Nk\mathbb(Z=k) \right)= \sum_{j=0}^N\mathbb{P}(Y=j)\mathbb{E}[Z]=\mathbb{E}[Z]
\end{equation} 
But this doesn't make sense...

Comment: It looks like that $X = Y + Z$, so $E[X] = ...$ (fill the blanks).

Comment: How did you get from $jP(Y = k)P(Z = j-k)$ to $k P(Y = j)P(Z = k)$? Note that $X$ has the same distribution as $Y + Z$, so $E[X] = E[Y] + E[Z]$.

Comment: @nicola why in your opinion $X=Y+Z$?

Comment: @Dominik I expanded the inner sum in the second row(first part) and I reach the equation after the equal sign...do you think there is a mistake there?

Comment: @andreasvr See that the distribution function of $X$ is just the convolution of $Y$ and $Z$. In other words, the probability of $X$ being a given $j$ value is obtained by the sum of the probabilities of every $Y$ and $Z$ combination that gives $j$.

Comment: @andreasvr Yes, the mistake seems to be there. To get the correct solution, decompose $j = (j - k) + k$ in front of the probability.